A creativity or imagination tag
What do people think of a creativity and/or imagination tag.. we have a lot of tags regarding mathematical intelligence..  
Is there a correlation between high IQ and creativity?

I think a "creativity" tag would be good. It's related to performance and intelligence but it is a discrete form of behaviour. 
Example questions:

Any studies on lack of imagination and creativity?
Is there a correlation between high IQ and creativity?


@WhyDoYouThinkThatIsTrue that seems enough to me to  apply the creativity tag. My rough rule would incorporate whether there has been any dissent on meta and also the likely disruption caused by applying the change. I.e., adding creativity tag to a few questions is not that disruptive.
